# MySQL disaster and recovery plans

Tags: mysql, disaster-recovery

Can someone guide me to some articles/plans related to MySQL disaster and recovery? In this moment I run a master/slave configuration (NDB is not acceptable because is not ACID compliant).

Comment: It's really not clear to me what your question is. At first I thought you wanted to earn about disaster recovery but then in your comment to Brent's answer you tell us you already know how to backup and restore. Perhaps you can clarify just what you're after.

Comment: I'm interested in plans of the disaster recovery. In other words, what can happen and how we can prevent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question seems to be really general, so I'll give an answer to match.

Read these two books, they'll cover pretty much everything!

- [MySQL High Availability](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596807290/)
- [High Performance MySQL](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596101718/)

Answer (score 1):

For backups / recovery, look at using mylvmbackup.

For HA / disaster, look at using MySQL's Master/Master replication, with heartbeart.

Comment: I'm most interested in the plans of doing that. I know how to take the backups and how to restore everything.